# `lein repl` leads to Java error in leiningen following hard drive crash

Tags: clojure, leiningen

My hard drive crashed earlier. It looks like my Clojure install was affected. When I try to do `lein repl` I am greeted with the following error.

```
$ lein repl
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:476)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:373)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:187)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl$connect.doInvoke(nrepl.clj:184)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.ack$send_ack.invoke(ack.clj:47)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.server$start_server.doInvoke(server.clj:146)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:619)
    at user$eval597.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6693)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6666)
    at clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2927)
    at leiningen.core.eval$fn__4815.invoke(eval.clj:314)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
    at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:337)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:160)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at leiningen.repl$server$fn__8776.invoke(repl.clj:203)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:628)
    at clojure.core$bound_fn_STAR_$fn__4140.doInvoke(core.clj:1884)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
REPL server launch timed out.
```

My leiningen install is via homebrew, so I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling.

```
$ brew rm --force leiningen
Uninstalling leiningen...

$ brew install leiningen
==> Downloading https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/archive/2.4.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/leiningen-2.4.2.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.4.2/leining
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/leiningen--jar-2.4.2.jar
==> Caveats
Dependencies will be installed to:
  $HOME/.m2/repository
To play around with Clojure run `lein repl` or `lein help`.

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/leiningen/2.4.2: 8 files, 13M, built in 2 seconds
```

No dice. I still get the same error. What broke and how do I fix it?

Edit:

Additional diagnostic info:

```
$ lein repl :headless
nREPL server started on port 56785 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:56785

$ lein repl :connect localhost:56785
Connecting to nREPL at localhost:56785
ConnectException Connection refused
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect (PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:527)
    java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:476)
    java.net.Socket.<init> (Socket.java:373)
    java.net.Socket.<init> (Socket.java:187)
    clojure.tools.nrepl/connect (nrepl.clj:184)
    clojure.core/apply (core.clj:624)
    clojure.tools.nrepl/add-socket-connect-method!/fn--5686 (nrepl.clj:226)
Bye for now!

$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.133 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.149 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.059/0.113/0.149/0.033 ms

$ lein repl :connect 127.0.0.1:56785
Connecting to nREPL at 127.0.0.1:56785
REPL-y 0.3.1
Clojure 1.6.0
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e
```

Comment: Do you have a localhost entry in your /etc/hosts? If so, what does it point to?

Comment: I do. My hosts file is: 127.0.0.1 localhost; 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost; ::1 localhost; fe80::1%lo0 localhost. My hostname is simply localhost.

Comment: I don't think you have a Clojure problem but a network configuration problem. Can you successfully open other network connections to localhost (ssh, samba, whatever)?

Comment: Yes. I can ssh to localhost. I can also use netcat to listen on the above nREPL port 56785 and then connect to it in another terminal session through localhost (`nc localhost 56785`).

Comment: Evidently if I change my hostname from localhost to anything else, the REPL now works. No clue why this issue manifested only after the crash.